# How can i select rows in sql statement which is not covered by the where clause?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i also want to display that if the product doesn't have status 'delivered' it will display its count as 0.. how can i do that?

```
  SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS Delivered
    FROM warehouse
   WHERE LatestStat = 'Delivered'
GROUP BY Product
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product, SUM(IF(LatestStat='Delivered', 1, 0)) AS Delivered
FROM warehouse
GROUP BY Product
```

If you use a `WHERE` clause then you will get only those records for which `LatestStat = 'Delivered'`. So here I have removed the WHERE clause to use all records and then I count the number of records which have been delivered.

Comment: it returned total count for each product...
i want it to return the product and the count of that product that is delivered... and if the count is 0... it will return 0

Comment: @bolekevora Please add some sample data in your question and expected results, so that I can update my query accordingly and help you better.

Comment: Product           Stock          Delivered
-Keyboard           2               0
-Mouse              1               3

thats the result that i want...

Comment: @bolekevora Please check my edit above and try now. I have replaced `count` with `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS Delivered
FROM warehouse
WHERE LatestStat = 'Delivered'
GROUP BY Product
Having COUNT(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS Delivered
        FROM warehouse
       WHERE LatestStat = 'Delivered'
    GROUP BY Product
    HAVING Delivered > 0
```